# Which line ending/newline to use?

Tags: newline, line-endings, eol

The web is full of explanations about the history of the newline schism. But I can't find an answer whether the world has finally agreed on one standard to end a line.

Given a Java project that is developed and used on linux and windows machines. Which would be the best choice for newlines in the source files: cr or crlf?

Would it make sense to convert all crlf to cr in an already existing codebase? Maybe do this together with an SVN to Git migration?

Comment: Scott Hanselamn posted a blog post about this a few days ago :)
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/YoureJustAnotherCarriageReturnLineFeedInTheWall.aspx

Answer (score 2):

EOLs are individual for each files

```
                                       | svn:eol-style |  Git attributes
For source code files --- native EOLs  |   native      |  !eol
For bash scripts --- LFs               |     LF        |  eol=lf
For bat scripts --- CRLFs              |    CRLF       |  eol=crlf
For binary files                       |  <not set>    |  -text
```

Have a look at this [post about EOLs](http://blog.subgit.com/line-endings-handling-in-svn-git-and-subgit/) for details.

Also have a look at .gitattributes in SVNKit repository (git clone http://svn.svnkit.com/git/svnkit) as an example of good usage of Git attributes for EOLs.